# Unable to turn on Wireless on a Lenovo Thinkpad 410s

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, thinkpad

I cannot turn on the wireless card on my Lenovo Thinkpad 410s running Windows 7.  It simply stopped working.  I tested with boot from disk and it works...not a hardware issue.  I have checked BIOS, reloaded drivers, etc.

I am out of ideas. Has anyone else had this problem? Has anyone solved the problem?

Comment: Does it have some kind of wireless switch utility software or some FN key combination you have to press? It's normally Fn+F5 on thinkpads.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean that "I tested with boot from disk and it doesn't work.."

Check the hardware switch on the right side (next to the Thinkpad mark on the palm rest), see picture below:

[image: Thinkpad T410s]

You can also run the self test programs that are included in ThinkVantage (press the blue button above F5). The test points can and example of the result are shown below:

[image: Test menu]

[image: Test results]

Answer (score 0):

pressing Fn+F5 in Windows brought up a control panel which allowed me to power it on my R400.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsofttranslator.com/BV.aspx?ref=IE8Activity&a=http%3A%2F%2Fdrivers.softpedia.com%2Fget%2FNETWORK-CARD%2FREALTEK%2FLenovo-ThinkPad-T410-Realtek-WLAN-Driver-10000298-for-Windows-7.shtml

this download worked for me.  Realtek wireless driver from softpedia.com

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.